# How to include headers for C compilation in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am a newbie to Gradle. I am trying to compile a set of source files which contain headers which are distributed across the project directory. My source directory structure does not comply with the Gradle convention. How do I add the header locations needed for compilation in my build.gradle? Attached here is my `build.gradle` file.

```
// build.gradle

apply plugin: 'c'

model {
    components {
        my_project (NativeExecutableSpec){
            sources {
                c {
                    source {
                        srcDir "my_proj_src/a/a1.1"
                        include "**/*.c"
                    }
                    exportedHeaders {
                        srcDir "my_proj_src/a/a1.1", "fsw/b/b1.2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does not work. And additionally, is there a possibility to do partial linking using Gradle?

EDIT: Additionally, I would like to also know how to make Gradle search recursively for headers within the source hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**exportedHeaders` are for exporting headers from the component itself, not for adding headers.** So this would not work.

**You would need to create a library and add it as the `api linkage`** so that those headers will be added to headers your component is compiled against:

```
model {
    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            ffmpegHeaders {
                headers.srcDirs "$ffmpegDir/include"
            }
        }
    }

    components {
        libUsingHeaders(NativeLibrarySpec) {
            sources {
                c {
                    lib library: 'ffmpegHeaders', linkage: 'api'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I sort of get the concept now. Additionally, I would like to know if it possible to make Gradle search recursively for headers. If yes, how?

Comment: AFAIK that will work automatically. You just define the root folder for headers and gradle will pass that to the appropriate compiler. Compilers usually recursively search in such directories. I do recommend to look at the "build/tmp/compileYourLibrary/options.txt" file. This is what is exactly passed to the compiler, including the headers file arguments.

Comment: Does this api linkage also work for assembler source set?

Comment: Not sure, but I would expect similar behavior.